# ajax request of json file from local

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, ajax-request

I wanted to retrieve my local JSON file data through an AJAX request. When I launch the html in Chrome, it yields the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Below is my code:

```
function getJSON(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "C:/Users/test/Documents/Demo/KendoTest/testJS/test.json",
                    type: "GET",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success:function(res){
                      //do something if successful
                    },
                    error:function(e, msg){
                        alert(JSON.stringify(e) + " " + msg);
                    }
                });
            }
```

If I add `dataType : 'jsonp',`

it returns me the error function.

Comment: Browser cannot access IO . Otherwise, it will be the catastrophe.

Comment: no possible way this will ever be allowed to work on any browser

Comment: why is that ? any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google chrome then add this extension to your chrome..
And after adding toggle on 'Enable cross-origin resource sharing'

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Hope it helps...